# AngularJs: disable anchor / ngif negated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive (hidden some sensitive values):

```
modApp.directive("dir1", [
function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            "results": "=",
            "allowView": "@",
            "allowPrint": "@",
        },
        templateUrl: "myurl",
        compile: function (elem, attrs) {
            // some code
        },
    };
}]);
```

and the template snippet is:

```
<a ng-href="#/MyUrl/{{item.code}}" target="_blank">
  <img class="img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{myUrlToImg}}">
</a>
```

So my issue is that I need to disable the anchor under certain security conditions.
Therefore when it is allowed, it is ok to show the anchor and the image.
But when it is not, it should only show the image.

The easy way would be to simply define something like:

```
<a ng-show="{{allowView}}"><img></a>
<img ng-hide="{{allowView}}"><img>
```

The problem that two requests to the image are generated, where it should only be one.

The ideal would be to have something like:

```
<a disabled></a>
```

I found a aDisabled directive here in SO, but it didn't work for me.

Also there is ng-if but I couldn't make it work with the negated value of allowView.

Any suggestions?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UJgQsaDYaxErP5A2NZy2
This plunker does not still use the allowView scope variable.
Note that in html, I'm setting a hardcoded true/false, it seems that this also has an impact, but not sure why...

Comment: add a plunkr with a demo please

Comment: plunkr please, would be easier

Comment: Why cannot you use the ng-if on anchor tag? It will hide or show all, even with child elements

Comment: ng-if should work here as usual. Dont afraid of some duplication in html: <a ng-if="show"><img>...</a><img ng-if="!show">

Comment: ng-disabled will never work on elements that are not meant to be disabled. `<a>` is either a text or a href, but I never saw a disabled link. ng-disabled will work on buttons, radio buttons checkboxes and other elements like that. If you want to avoid double post request to the server, why not to use ng-src for image and have this blank when that should be hidden?

Comment: the image needs to always be shown, like the user profile photo. The link is what needs to be deactivated because it is assumed that the user can search but he cannot go further than that (I know it may be a weird use case but it can happen in my system)